# How to use axios HttpService from Nest.js to make a POST request

Tags: nestjs

I am trying to make a POST request using `@nestjs/axios` and then access the response.

This is my code so far:

```js
verifyResponse(captcha_response: String): Observable<AxiosResponse<any>> {

    return this.httpService.post('some url', {
        captcha_response
    });
}
```

However, I am unsure how to access the response data. If I use `console.log()` to view the response I get this:

```
Observable { _subscribe: [Function (anonymous)] }
```

I'm new to both Nest.js and the concept of an Observable. I would be grateful for an example to make a HTTP request and access the response data.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you want to make the `HttpService` use a promise instead of  on [RxJS Observable](https://rxjs.dev) you can use `lastValueFrom` wrapping around the `this.httpService.post()` call. This will transform the Observable into a promise and you can `await` it as normal. Otherwise, if you just return the observable, Nest will handle waiting for the response for you. Either way, you'll need to make sure to use that `map((resp) => resp.data)` function you have so you don't end up with circular data in the response object (as Axios's response object is circular by design).

If you're trying to `console.log()` the data, you'll want to use `tap` along with `map` in the form of

```js
this.httpService.post(url, data, options).pipe(
  tap((resp) => console.log(resp)),
  map((resp) => resp.data),
  tap((data) =>  console.log(data)),
);
```

`tap` is essentially a spy method to tap into the observable, look at the data, and let it pass through. It *can* mutate the data, but generally it's a good idea to leave that to `map` or other [rxjs operators](https://learnrxjs.io).

---

For just the simple `await` ability, something like this is all that's needed

```js
const data = await lastValueFrom(
  this.httpService.post(url, data, options).pipe(
    map(resp => res.data)
  )
);
```

**Example with `AxiosRequestConfig` object type (TypeScript)**

```js
const requestConfig: AxiosRequestConfig = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER',
  },
  params: {
    param1: 'YOUR_VALUE_HERE'
  },
};

const responseData = await lastValueFrom(
  this.httpService.post(requestUrl, null, requestConfig).pipe(
    map((response) => {
      return response.data;
    }),
  ),
);
```

Comment: I am getting this error -  Cannot find name 'map'. Did you mean 'Map'?ts(2552)
lib.es2015.collection.d.ts(56, 13): 'Map' is declared here.

Comment: `map` is an RxJS operator, imported as `import { map } from 'rxjs'`

Answer (score 1):

`AxiosResponse` should be imported from `axios`:

```js
import { AxiosResponse } from 'axios'
```

You can make use of import suggestions by pressing `ctrl`+`space` (or `options` + `esc` on mac) or by using `ctrl`+`.`

Answer (score 0):

Exampe with 'axiosRef.request':

```
const config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
  url,
  method,
  params,
  headers,
  data,
};

try {
  const response = await this.httpService.axiosRef.request(config);
  return response.data;
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

Exampe with 'axiosRef.post':

```
try {
  const url = `some url`;
  const data = {};
  return await this.httpService.axiosRef.post(url, data);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```