# NestJs: How to upload file async httpService

Tags: file-upload, nestjs, multer

I am learning how to upload files with nestjs. Specifically if my submission form has a title and an image file. I want the photo to be saved after I check some conditions. I have created an api to upload then use HttpService but it doesn't seem to work.

This is the upload controller:

```
@Post('/image')
  @UseGuards(AdminAuthGuard)
  @ApiOperation({ summary: 'Upload image Api ' })
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file', optionsImage))
  async upload(@UploadedFile('file') file): Promise<{ filename: any }> {
    return { filename: `/image/${file.filename}` };
  }
```

I tried like this, but it doesn't work:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file)
await this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/upload/image', formData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nest's `HttpService` returns an `Observable` which is by default not-awaitable (it's not a Promise). It can be turned into a promise by being wrapped with `lastValueFrom` (from the `rxjs` package) or you can use rxjs operators to handle the response and return the Observable. [Lots of extra information here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60908571/how-to-process-axios-httpservice-observable-response/60908801#60908801) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69139950/how-to-use-axios-httpservice-from-nest-js-to-make-a-post-request/69139996#69139996)

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Thank you.